# Cinnamon is discoloring my icing

Tags: cinnamon

After a day or two, the cinnamon smear baked in my cinnamon rolls and twists bleed a yellow>orange>green color/oil into my white icing.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: have you got a photo of the effect you want to avoid? what have you tried?

Comment: Is this "cinnamon smear" just real cinnamon, or is it some processed product which may contain, in addition to cinnamon, food colorings which might be bleeding into the icing. I have never seen the brown color of plain, real, cinnamon split into any other component colors in the way that ink or brown marker does. Would be interesting to see a picture of this if you have one.

Comment: I will get a photo up soon. It's real cinnamon with no additional colouring. I believe it's the oils of the cinnamon leaching out onto the icing...